# NestedScrollView with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/divider"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/wall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"

                android:tint="#11000000"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.9"/>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main.framelayout.title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.3">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main.linearlayout.title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/profile_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="bottom|center"
                        android:text="Amit Kumar yadav"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="24sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/profile_status"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:text="@string/quila_tagline"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="14dp"
                            android:layout_height="14dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_love"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/relationship"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="Single"
                            android:textSize="12dp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardProfileRates"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="8dp">

             // 2-3 linear layout

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/userInfo"
                android:layout_below="@id/cardProfileRates"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                   // 2-3 linear layout

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/userPhotos"
                android:layout_below="@+id/userInfo"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:padding="10dp"
                >


                </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_below="@+id/userPhotos"
                android:id="@+id/user_posts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
             app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                >

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar99"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

        app:layout_anchor="@id/main.framelayout.title"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:title="">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Space
                android:layout_width="@dimen/image_final_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image_final_width"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/quila_name2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePic"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/face"
        app:civ_border_color="@android:color/white"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
        app:finalHeight="@dimen/image_final_width"
        app:finalYPosition="2dp"
        app:layout_behavior="in.fabits.fabits.AvatarImageBehavior"
        app:startHeight="2dp"
        app:startToolbarPosition="2dp"
        app:startXPosition="2dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The problem is that when i open this activity every thing above recyclerview i.e., (1 cardview and 2 LinearLayout) are pushed up and only recyclerview is showing by default.

To see my cardview and linearlayout i have to scrollup to see i.e, recyclerview is getting somehow focus by default.

I have also tried

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, false);
```

but it makes no change.

so i trying to get cardview visible(or on focus) because it is above recyclerview is that possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no meaning of putting one Scrollable view into another. If you are going with `recyclerview`, you can consider different `item_type` to add into `recyclerview`. There are plenty of tutorials available on Internet.

This is one of 'em - [Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView)

Comment: that means i have to add my views above the recycler view into the recyclerview

Comment: Exactly.. you can add anywhere in fact, within `recyclerview`.